How do show how many connections are made?
When running a personal hotspot the title bar says "1 connection" in the header after connect. Does that mean it can allow more connections?
Side note:
It's the most limiting hotspot I've ever seen and it displays the password in plain text. As soon as you open the hotspot, if you are working at a coffee shop for example, anyone can look over your shoulder and see it.

Most basic settings of a router:
(1 of 8 screens of settings)

Where does it show how many connections there are? And can I set the limit of connections?

If this is an Apple device connecting to an Apple-provided hotspot, you don't ever need to open the settings.  All you need to have is for both devices to be signed into the same AppleID and for Bluetooth to be turned on so they can see each other.

How long do you that Settings page open in a coffee shop to pair a new device (one which was paired before will already know the password)? Anyway, if you need additional features in iOS, please use the appropriate page on https://www.apple.com/feedback/

@nohillside to use a personal hotspot on iOS devices you have to open the hotspot screen (nd leave it open until the other device connects) and that screen shows the password in plain text. it doesn't connect otherwise. look at the screenshot (now discoverable). i would fire the people that approved this.

I never have to do that, usually my phone stays locked when I connect (if the hotspot functionality is enabled of course).

I noticed that if I go to the home screen and then open an app, the title bar briefly shows how many connections there are.
I still don't see an option to limit the number of connections.
